# python xarray open_dataset unable to read the second, third, or more nc file

Tags: netcdf, python-xarray

I tried to read different NetCDF file by xarray, but it only read the first file. While the second, third, and more NetCDF files were read as the first file without any error. Anyone knows how to solve this problem?

```
### read files

## VI
VI_terra = xr.open_dataset(data_vi+"MOD13A1.006_500m_aid0001.nc")
VI_aqua = xr.open_dataset(data_vi+"MYD13A1.006_500m_aid0001.nc")

## LAI
LAI = xr.open_dataset(data_lai+"MCD15A2H.006_500m_aid0001.nc")

## ET
ET_terra = xr.open_dataset(data_et+"MOD16A2GF.006_500m_aid0001.nc")
ET_aqua = xr.open_dataset(data_et+"MYD16A2GF.006_500m_aid0001.nc")

## Surface temperature
Tsurf_terra = xr.open_dataset(data_tsurf+"MOD11A2.006_1km_aid0001.nc")
Tsurf_aqua = xr.open_dataset(data_tsurf+"MYD11A2.006_1km_aid0001.nc")
```

But the LAI is misread as VI_terra:

[image]

While when I use ncdump to check LAI, the file itself doesn't have problem (differ from VI):
[image]

Comment: Just guessing, but can you try it with `cache=False` added to `open_dataset()`?

Comment: Thanks, Bart. I restarted kernel and tried to added `cache=Fasle` to all the `open_dataset()`, but nothing change. it still returns only the first reading (VI_terra) for all the following dataset.

Comment: What happens if you read them with [NetCDF4](https://pypi.org/project/netCDF4/)? Does that result in the same problem?

Comment: It is still the same. I read it as `VI_terra = netCDF4.Dataset(data_vi+"MOD13A1.006_500m_aid0001.nc", "r")` and `LAI = netCDF4.Dataset(data_lai+"MCD15A2H.006_500m_aid0001.nc", "r")`. Then LAI still returns me VI_terra's data.

Comment: Are the files large? Can you share them somewhere?

Comment: The file is about 15MB to 45MB. I put some of the data (VI_terra, VI_aqua and LAI) in the share file here (might take some time to upload, my wifi is slow): https://www.dropbox.com/s/g8lk5bpy69j77mi/File_share_MODIS_stackoverflow.7z?dl=0

Comment: Hi @Bart, it just finished upload. Thank you for the willing taking a look!

Comment: I downloaded the data, but can't reproduce the problem. See https://pastebin.com/wRyP3sWR for my results.

Comment: Thank you for trying out, Bart. I'm not sure what's going on with my laptop, probably some part of setting is wrong. I will try to go around doing one by one on my laptop or get other computer to run my code for now. Will update here if I find out what's wrong. Thanks again for helping!

Comment: @Yu-Fen one of my colleagues is having this exact issue, did you ever mange to resolve it?

Comment: @turnerm There wasn't a direct solution.  It's been a while, so I might not remember exactly how I went through this issue - I remembered that I found if I use another desktop with Linux system, then I wouldn't have this issue.  So I either solved the problem by using another PC, or converted the netCDF info into data frame, then close it, and go to the next netCDF file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `xr.open_dataset`, the .nc files remain open after reading.

The easiest solution is to use [`xr.load_dataset`](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.load_dataset.html), which closes the .nc file automatically after reading.

If you need to stick with `xr.open_dataset` then you can place it in a `with` statement, or call `.close()` when finished.